# How do I calculate the Fourier-transform of $f(t) = \max(t-1,0) (t \in \mathbb{R})$?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

I get

$$\hat f(w) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\max(t-1,0)e^{-i\omega t}dt$$
$$= -\int_{-\infty}^{1}(t-1)e^{-i\omega t}dt$$
$$ = \lim_{p\to\infty}\left(\int_{-p}^1e^{-i\omega t} - \int_{-p}^1 t\cdot e^{-i\omega t}\right)$$
$$ = \lim_{p\to\infty}\left[\frac{e^{-i\omega p}}{-i\omega p} - \frac{e^{-i\omega t}(i\omega p -1)}{-\omega^2}\right]^1_{-p}$$

But then I get stuck with limits of imaginary numbers...?

Comment: You will have to regularize you integral.

Answer (score 1):

For your problem, the Fourier transform in terms of real variables does not exist. So we should understand that $\omega \in \mathbb{C}$.

We want to find
$$\hat{f}(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\!dt\,\max(t-1,0) e^{-i \omega t} = \int_{0}^\infty\!dt(t-1) e^{-i \omega t}.$$

The integral only converges in the half-plane with $\mathop{\rm Im}\omega <0$. So assuming this, we obtain
$$\hat f(\omega) = \int_1^\infty (t-1) e^{-i\omega t}
= \frac{(1+i t \omega) e^{- i \omega t}}{\omega^2} + \frac{e^{- i\omega t}}{i\omega}\biggl|_{t=1}^\infty.$$

Now as $\lim_{t\to\infty} p(t) e^{-i \omega t} =0$ for any polynomial $p(t)$, the contribution from the upper limit vanishes and we obtain the result
$$ \hat f(\omega) = -\frac{e^{-i \omega}}{\omega^2}.$$

For the back-transform, note that the contour has to be chosen such as to keep $\hat f(\omega)$ within the region of definition, i.e., $\mathop{\rm Im}\omega <0$.

Comment: Are you sure about $\hat f$? I get additional terms with $\delta$ and $\delta'$ when i compute it.